# Weekly Email of Channel Entries

Tags: email, postmaster, notification

We need to be able to email subscribed members (that we add to Mailchimp via Postmaster) a weekly email of the latest posts made to the site.

Can anyone point me in the right direction and provide some tips on how we can accomplish this?

Thanks!
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should install the RSS module which is provided.
Then you would create an RSS Template in this form:

```
{exp:rss:feed channel="your_news_channel" debug="yes" status="open" }
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{encoding}"?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
    <atom:link href="http://yourdomain.com/path-to/rss-template" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />  
    <title>Our cool website</title>
    <link>http://yourdomain.com</link>
    <description>News from Our cool website</description>
    <dc:language>{channel_language}</dc:language>
    <dc:creator>info@yourdomain.com</dc:creator>
    <dc:rights>Copyright {gmt_date format="%Y"}</dc:rights>
    <dc:date>{gmt_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
    <admin:generatorAgent rdf:resource="http://expressionengine.com/" />
{exp:channel:entries channel="your_news_channel" limit="10" dynamic_start="on" disable="member_data" sort="asc" status="open|featured"}
    <item>
      <title>{exp:xml_encode}{title}{/exp:xml_encode}</title>
      <link>{comment_url_title_auto_path}</link>
      <guid>{comment_url_title_auto_path}#When:{gmt_entry_date format="%H:%i:%sZ"}</guid>
      <description><![CDATA[{news_excerpt_tag}]]></description> 
      <dc:date>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
    </item>
{/exp:channel:entries}
    </channel>
</rss>
{/exp:rss:feed}
```

Test this template by navigating with your browser to `http://yourdomain.com/path-to/rss-template`

Then create an RSS driven campaign on Mailchimp and give the above address as an RSS feed URL. (Campaigns/Create Campaign/Rss Driven Campaign).
Then you will be given the opportunity to configure the campaign to be sent at set intervals (in your case weekly), given the fact new entries are found. Follow the RSS merge tags instructions to provide a template. http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/rss-in-campaigns/create-an-rss-driven-campaign

Comment: I never even thought about doing it that way! Thank you very much!